# Heroku assests precompile fails with coffee-rails-3.2.2

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, assets, cedar

I have been running into this issue recently on Heroku and can't seem to figure out how to correct it. The application is Rails 3.2.x application running on ruby 1.9.3. It runs fine locally but when deployed to heroku, the precompile phase for the assets fails. The heroku web dyno stack is cedar.

I have already set the 'config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false' in the application.rb file.

Below is the error received when deploying.

```
Counting objects: 7, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 438 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
    Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
    Using rake (10.0.3)
    Using i18n (0.6.4)
    Using multi_json (1.6.1)
    Using activesupport (3.2.12)
    Using builder (3.0.4)
    Using activemodel (3.2.12)
    Using erubis (2.7.0)
    Using journey (1.0.4)
    Using rack (1.4.5)
    Using rack-cache (1.2)
    Using rack-test (0.6.2)
    Using hike (1.2.1)
    Using tilt (1.3.4)
    Using sprockets (2.2.2)
    Using actionpack (3.2.12)
    Using mime-types (1.21)
    Using polyglot (0.3.3)
    Using treetop (1.4.12)
    Using mail (2.4.4)
    Using actionmailer (3.2.12)
    Using arel (3.0.2)
    Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
    Using activerecord (3.2.12)
    Using activeresource (3.2.12)
    Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    Using coffee-script-source (1.5.0)
    Using execjs (1.4.0)
    Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
    Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
    Using json (1.7.7)
    Using rdoc (3.12.2)
    Using thor (0.17.0)
    Using railties (3.2.12)
    Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
    Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    Using warden (1.2.1)
    Using devise (2.2.3)
    Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
    Using pg (0.12.2)
    Using bundler (1.3.2)
    Using rails (3.2.12)
    Using rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
    Using sass (3.2.6)
    Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
    Using uglifier (1.3.0)
    Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
    Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
    Running: rake assets:precompile
    rake aborted!
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/rails/generators/coffee/assets/templates/javascript.js.coffee isn't in paths: /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/app/assets/images, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/app/assets/javascripts, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/app/assets/stylesheets, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/assets/fonts, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/assets/javascripts, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/assets/stylesheets, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/assets/venera_images, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts, /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-2.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/asset_attributes.rb:42:in `logical_path'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:160:in `find_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `new'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:270:in `circular_call_protection'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:248:in `build_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
    /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
    Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
    Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
    http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
-----> Rails plugin injection
    Injecting rails_log_stdout
    Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
    Procfile declares types     -> (none)
    Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 20.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v25
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2.1'

gem 'rubygems-bundler', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 2.2.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13.0'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.5.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_tree ../../../vendor
 */
```

applcation.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require_tree ../../../vendor
```

This is suppose to be running on ruby 1.9.3 yet I see /tmp/build_18zpsldi56ucr/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ in the gems path. Not sure if that is the issue. Has anyone run into this problem on heroku before. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I just posted the same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449363/heroku-coffee-rails-failure-in-asset-precompile and have had no answers

Answer (score 0):

Since the gems under the `:assets` group are not used in production, you should move the `gem 'coffee-rails'` line outside that group.

Also i **don't** think you need this line in your application.js `*= require_tree ../../../vendor`

Comment: From what I understand, Sprockets ignore css and js files in the pipeline. The ../../../vendor is there because that directory has js and css files.

Comment: try //=require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.