# heroku coffee-rails failure in asset precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

Deploying Rails 3.2.14, Ruby 2.0.0 to heroku

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 895 bytes, done.
Total 9 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.5)
       Using multi_json (1.8.0)
       Using activesupport (3.2.14)
       Using builder (3.0.4)
       Using activemodel (3.2.14)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using journey (1.0.4)
       Using rack (1.4.5)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.2.2)
       Using actionpack (3.2.14)
       Using mime-types (1.25)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.14)
       Using arel (3.0.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activerecord (3.2.14)
       Using activeresource (3.2.14)
       Using acts_as_list (0.1.4)
       Using authlogic (3.3.0)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Using json (1.7.7)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (3.2.14)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using hpricot (0.8.5)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using kgio (2.8.1)
       Using netrc (0.7.7)
       Using pg (0.17.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using rails (3.2.14)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using raindrops (0.12.0)
       Using relax (0.0.7)
       Using remit (2.0.1)
       Using sass (3.2.11)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Using uglifier (2.2.1)
       Using unicorn (4.6.3)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (0.56s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/Rakefile:7)
       Compiled jquery.js  (4ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled common.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled dashboard.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled focus_first.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled goals.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled grade_book.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled group_weights.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled jquery.mustmatch.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled marketing.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled planning.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled printout.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled report_card.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled welcome.js  (50ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled jjmenu.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled jquery-1.7.1.min.js  (1ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled jquery-ui-1.9.2.all.min.js  (2ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled jquery.editinplace.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled jquery.tools.1.2.7.min.js  (0ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled vendor.js  (1ms)  (pid 677)
       Compiled coffee-script.js  (3ms)  (pid 677)
       rake aborted!
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/rails/generators/coffee/assets/templates/javascript.js.coffee isn't in paths: /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/app/assets/images, /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/app/assets/javascripts, /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/app/assets/stylesheets, /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/assets/javascripts, /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/assets/stylesheets, /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts, /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/asset_attributes.rb:42:in `logical_path'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:160:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `new'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:270:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:248:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_f609f0ad-2ede-4c7f-99c1-136d38969400/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
-----> DEPRECATIONS:
```

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ../../../vendor
//= require_tree .
```

application.css:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ../../../vendor
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.14)
      actionpack (= 3.2.14)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (3.2.14)
      activemodel (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.14)
      activemodel (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.14)
      activemodel (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
    activesupport (3.2.14)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts_as_list (0.1.4)
    arel (3.0.2)
    authlogic (3.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    debugger (1.6.2)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.2.3)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hpricot (0.8.5)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    kgio (2.8.1)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25)
    multi_json (1.8.0)
    netrc (0.7.7)
    pg (0.17.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.14)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.14)
      actionpack (= 3.2.14)
      activerecord (= 3.2.14)
      activeresource (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.14)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (3.2.14)
      actionpack (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.12.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    relax (0.0.7)
      hpricot (>= 0.6)
    remit (2.0.1)
      relax (~> 0.0.7)
    sass (3.2.11)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.2.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.6.3)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activesupport (~> 3.2)
  acts_as_list (= 0.1.4)
  authlogic (~> 3.2)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  debugger
  factory_girl_rails
  jquery-rails
  json (= 1.7.7)
  netrc
  pg (~> 0.14)
  rails (~> 3.2)
  rails_12factor
  rake
  remit (= 2.0.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  unicorn
```

I am able to run rake assets:precompile locally, without error, but the output indicates the assets are compiled twice?

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/jeff/dev/scholaric/Rakefile:7)
/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@scholaric-2.0.0/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/jeff/dev/scholaric/Rakefile:7)
Compiled jquery.js  (2ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled common.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled dashboard.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled focus_first.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled goals.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled grade_book.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled group_weights.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery.mustmatch.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled marketing.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled planning.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled printout.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled report_card.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled welcome.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jjmenu.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery-1.7.1.min.js  (1ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery-ui-1.9.2.all.min.js  (2ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery.editinplace.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery.tools.1.2.7.min.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled vendor.js  (1ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled application.js  (90ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled 960.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled bootstrap.min.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled dateinput.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jjmenu.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled overlay.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled tabs.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled dashboard.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled grade_book.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled group_weights.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled marketing.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled natural.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled planning.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled printout.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled report_card.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled reset.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled scholaric.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled text.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled welcome.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled application.css  (81ms)  (pid 15640)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/jeff/dev/scholaric/Rakefile:7)
Compiled jquery.js  (3ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled common.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled dashboard.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled focus_first.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled goals.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled grade_book.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled group_weights.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery.mustmatch.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled marketing.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled planning.js  (27ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled printout.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled report_card.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled welcome.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jjmenu.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery-1.7.1.min.js  (1ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery-ui-1.9.2.all.min.js  (2ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery.editinplace.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jquery.tools.1.2.7.min.js  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled vendor.js  (1ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled application.js  (121ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled 960.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled bootstrap.min.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled dateinput.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled jjmenu.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled overlay.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled tabs.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled dashboard.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled grade_book.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled group_weights.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled marketing.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled natural.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled planning.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled printout.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled report_card.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled reset.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled scholaric.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled text.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled welcome.css  (0ms)  (pid 15640)
Compiled application.css  (63ms)  (pid 15640)
```

A Few things I've noticed:

- I don't have any coffee script! Why does it search for it?
- In any case, the coffee-rails gem IS being bundled in with the app
- Does not seem to matter which configuration setting I choose for bundling the assets group in application.rb:

see this code:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Any ideas why this won't precompile on Heroku?

Comment: Can you paste your Gemfile.lock somewhere? I think coffee-rails gem is getting loaded from somewhere!

Comment: I thought that the `rails_12factor` gem was just for Rails 4 apps. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile` too?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku support actually was not able to determine why this was failing.  Instead they asked me to

1. Move all vendor/assets/javascripts files to app/assets/javascripts
2. Move all vendor/assets/stylesheets files to app/assets/stylesheets
3. Modify my manifests to replace //= require_tree ../../../vendor with requires of individual files.

Also, different issue, but I had to fix this later, and perhaps fixing it now will help??? -

1. Add the appropriate files to config.assets.precompile in config/environments/production.rb

They said they've never seen this issue before, so you may want to raise it with them, so it receives proper attention.

Comment: Generally I would say including the entire vendor directory is a bad idea. Since the vendor directory is added to the paths that are searched, you can simply require an asset by name. For example, if you had something like `vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.min.js` you could simply require it with `//= require jquery.min`

Comment: Also, loading assets in a particular order is important. When you require an entire directory, you can't be sure that one asset is loaded before another that may require it. For example if you have a jQuery plugin required before jQuery itself, it will not work. So it's a good practice to explicitly require your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I think the problem lies with the `rails_12factor` gem.

I think the problem may be because the `coffee-rails` gem is not being loaded correctly. Since this is a Rails 3.2 app, your Gemfile probably lists the `coffee-rails` gem in an `assets` group. In Rails 4, they removed the `assets` group, so if the `coffee-rails` gem is in an `assets` group and `rails_12factor` gem is assuming that it's not, then that might be the problem.

Also, even though you haven't written any Coffeescript, some of the gems that you have included may require Coffeescript. In fact, their expected Coffeescript compiler gem expectation may be different that the one that is being included.